# ¿Cómo elegir con random una función?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Estoy intentando ejecutar varios funciones de forma aleatoria, pero no sé como hacerlo con random. Intente con algo como

```
def suma()
    return num1 + num2
```

y lo que quiero saber es si se puede hacer algo tipo `random.choice(suma(), resta())`

Comment: la cantidad de funciones parece ser estática, así que puedes decidir si el random está entre 0 y 0.5, usas suma; si está entre 0.5 y 1, usas resta.

Comment: pero tengo como 30 cosas q añadir, entonces es para hacerlo mas optimo, me refiero he dicho suma y resta para explicarlo, pero tengo como muchas funciones

Answer (score 6):

Si se puede. Después que estén definidas las funciones, los nombres de las mismas pueden ser parte de otros objetos como listas:

```
import random

def suma(a, b):
    return f'La suma es {a+b}'

def resta(a, b):
    return f'La resta es {a-b}'

def mult(a, b):
    return f'La multiplicacion es {a*b}'

def div(a, b):
    return f'La division es {a/b}' if b != 0 else 'Division por cero'

a = 10
b = 5
op = [suma, resta, mult, div]
res = random.choice(op)(a, b)

print(res) # La division es 2.0
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Hola @Michael recuerda que si te sirvió la respuesta, puedes aceptarla y así la gente ve que eso fue lo que solucionó tu problema. Para hacer esto, solo debes clicar el "visto" verde al lado de la respuesta. :)